# R - can't merge dataframe after installing config package

Tags: r

After I install the config package, I can no longer use merge function on my dataframes.  I am getting error message "merge in error, ..., unused arguments."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `config` has a `merge()` function which overrides the `base` function.

Type `base::merge()` to get the base R function.

EDIT: or as pointed out by @PoGibas, don't load `config` and use `config::merge`.

Comment: I have a lot of codes using the merge function, is there a way to fix this without adding base:: to every call?  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith you can use `config` package functions with `config::function` instead of loading it. Might be more logical than overwriting `base` `R` functions.

Comment: @JohnSmith btw even in their [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/config/vignettes/introduction.html) code they don't load the package and use it with `config::package`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to address the problem of `config` masking `base::merge()` is to load the `config` package, use it to configure the environment, and then use `detach()` to remove the package. This will unmask `base::merge()`.

```
library(config)
# use config functions to set up environment
#
```

At this point we can show that `config::merge` is the default by printing the `merge()` function.

```
> merge
function (base_config, merge_config) 
{
    merge_lists(base_config, merge_config, recursive = TRUE)
}
<bytecode: 0x7fcddf5de488>
<environment: namespace:config>
>
```

To restore `base::merge()` as the default, we use the `detach()` function.

```
detach(package:config)
# at this point base::merge() and base::get() are unmasked
```

To demonstrate this, we'll print the `merge()` function again.

```
> detach(package:config)
> # print merge function to show it is from base package 
> merge
function (x, y, ...) 
UseMethod("merge")
<bytecode: 0x7fcde7c08e70>
<environment: namespace:base>
>
```