# R - how to make base "merge" function the default one

Tags: r, merge

I'm quite an R newbie, so apologizes if mine is a simple question.
I have many R scripts that use the base merge function. Yesterday, I had to install the config library and that completely screwed up the merge function since it's also defined inside congif.
I read this useful post: [R - can't merge dataframe after installing config package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164281/r-cant-merge-dataframe-after-installing-config-package)
but my question here is different.
I can't go through tens of R scripts and replace "merge()" with "base::merge()".

So my very simple question is the following and very similar to what discussed here:
[R: 2 functions with the same name in 2 different packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564564/r-2-functions-with-the-same-name-in-2-different-packages)

how can I specify to use the "base::" version of the function "merge()" as default one?
Or - is there a way to not install the "merge()" function contained inside the config package?
Many thanks

Comment: If you're only using a few functions from config, you might be best not to load it, but to call the function explicitly with "config::function_name()"

Comment: The accepted answer to the second linked question seems to offer an alternative solution, after `library(config)` do `merge <- base::merge`

Comment: 10s of scripts doesn't seem like that many. You can do a global find/replace in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: you're right guys, find/replace is not a big deal - but I was scared because on the server we have hundreds and more of R script so I didn't want to replace other people's code. The solution posted below by Len is actually fixing my specific problem, thanks to the use of the detach function. Much appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer to [R - can't merge data frame after installing config package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164281/r-cant-merge-dataframe-after-installing-config-package) directs the user to explicitly reference functions from the `config` package as `config::merge()` or `config::get()`.

Another way to address the problem of `config` masking `base::merge()` is to load the `config` package, use it to configure the environment, and then use `detach()` to remove the package. This will unmask `base::merge()`.

```
library(config)
# use config functions to set up environment
#
```

At this point we can show that `config::merge` is the default by printing the `merge()` function.

```
> merge
function (base_config, merge_config) 
{
    merge_lists(base_config, merge_config, recursive = TRUE)
}
<bytecode: 0x7fcddf5de488>
<environment: namespace:config>
>
```

To restore `base::merge()` as the default, we use the `detach()` function.

```
detach(package:config)
# at this point base::merge() and base::get() are unmasked
```

To demonstrate this, we'll print the `merge()` function again.

```
> detach(package:config)
> # print merge function to show it is from base package 
> merge
function (x, y, ...) 
UseMethod("merge")
<bytecode: 0x7fcde7c08e70>
<environment: namespace:base>
>
```

Comment: Thank you Len, you're right, if I detach it after I use it, then merge() is not "masked" by the merge function defined in config. Very very useful. Thank you

Comment: @Angelo - You're welcome, Angelo. My answer to [What is the difference between the workspace and the environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60962116/what-is-the-difference-between-the-workspace-and-the-environments/60962508#60962508) illustrates how loading a package inserts it between the Global Environment and the environment of the most recently loaded package. Since the `base` environment is second to last in the environment search path, any package loaded in an R session that includes functions with the same names as ones in `base` will mask the functions from `base`.